# Address based on marker (Oracle Apex Pages)

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, oracle-apex, google-geocoder

I know how to integrate map on the apex page, read `geocode` from the table and array. I know how to retrieve `geocode` based on address from the user (text fields) but I need help with reading `geocode` from markers, what I mean is that I need to enable user to click on the map and display the marker or set default marker which is draggable and get the 'geocode' with address from the marker to the table (text fields).

I do not know how to enable user to click on map and get a marker, all what he can do is drag the page using the hand icon on the map (which is by default when you integrate Google maps).

Comment: It does not look like a question about APEX. Probably, you need to add tags related to google maps and/or javascript.

Comment: I know its a javascript and probably I need to add a variable called marker but than I do not how to apply it to the map as I'm not expert on javascript.

Comment: http://orclapex.blogspot.co.uk

This is one link that I found but this one just gives me longitude and latitude and not the full address with postcodes

Comment: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html

This is another page I found but it does not output the details to the textfield and I do not know how to integrate this to the APEX pages.